# TF.RECORDS IMAGES TENSORFLOW

Tags: python, tensorflow, decode, conv-neural-network, tfrecord

I'm doing a Tensorflow CNN. At the time of reading my `tf.records` I do not know what type of data is appropriate when I decode my images. I saw in multiple tutorials that a reshape should be done before entering the model. I'd like to know if I'm doing it the right way. This is my code:

```
def read_file(filename_queue):

   #Funcion para leer el archivo tf.record, y retornamos el next recrod
   reader=tf.TFRecordReader()
   _,serialized_example=reader.read(filename_queue)

  #Se decodifica el tf.record retornando un diccionario 
  feature={'train/image':tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
         'train/label':tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)}
  features=tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,features=feature)

  #Convertimos el string a numeros de los decodificados features
  image=tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'],tf.float32)* (1 / 255.0)

  #Convertimos a datos
  label=tf.cast(features['train/label'],dtype=tf.int32)

  #Reshape data
  image=tf.reshape(image,[224,224,3])   

  return image,label
```

Comment: Please post links to the tutorials

Comment: LINKS: http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html

Comment: LINKS:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py